# Heritage of the names of the monad operators

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm currently reading up on category theory basics and try to make sense of the names Haskell assigns to monad operations, semantically.

All material I've come through refers to `return` as the unit map and `join` as the multiplication map (I'm OK with the name "join"). For `>>=` or `bind` I haven't even (yet) found a name common in math. Rather I've come across its flipped form, `lift` or -*, which in turn makes sense to me.

Actual questions (tldr):

1. Why was "return" used instead of "unit"?
2. Why was "bind" coined as nomenclature?
3. Is there a name for "bind" in math world?
4. What are the semantics the names "bind" and "return" should imply?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both names come from programming, rather than math. `return`, being used as the last statement of the `do` expression, makes it look very imperative: `do {do_something; return result}`. `bind`'s name comes from its `do` translation: `action >>= \x -> something` translates to `do {x <- action; something}`, which looks like `x` is bound to the value returned from `action`.

As for `bind`'s analog in math world, google "Kleisli triple".

Comment: BTW, the naming of `return` is frequently considered to have been a mistake, since it doesn't really behave much like imperative `return` at all in any but the simplest cases.